# SelectPicker in UpdatePanel disappear when Asyncpostback

Tags: c#, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

It's my first question, I'm sorry for my bad English skill.

I have problem about `<select class="form-control selectpicker"</select>` in UpdatePanel, it disappears when I clicked on a button (button's in a UpdatePanel too)

Here's my aspx code

=========================================================================
[image]

=========================================================================
[image: Clicked On a button so my <select> is disappear T_T]

=========================================================================

## [image: It's all my code.]

How do I do?

Comment: Please edit your question and copy your code in as text not an image, images can't be searched for text, and screenreaders can't read the code from them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done

In .aspx use this

```
 function test() {
            $("#<%=this.SelectAcademicYear.ClientID%>").selectpicker();
        }
```

then use this in Page_Load .aspx.cs

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "anything", "test();", true);
```

Answer (score 5):

Was having the same problem and this really helped me out. What you have works great, but this also does the same thing for me without having to use the test function and `ScriptManager`.

```
<script>
    function pageLoad() {
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker(); 
    }
</script>
```

where I had `CssClass="selectpicker"` attached to the `dropdownlist`.